# Constant Rerender when downloading an image (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to download an image from AWS, display it in my React component, and then on a button click, load a new image. The problem I am facing is that every time I go to load a new image, the page loads image after image, and won't stop rerendering with new images.

Here is my code for the landing page:

```
import React from 'react';
import Background from './Media/marmaduke2.jpg';
import Comic from'./Comic.js';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export default function RandomarmLanding() {

    const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
    const [isReal, setIsReal] = useState(false)
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState('')
    async function getComics() {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/comics')
        const data = await response.json()
        setCaption(data['caption'])
        setIsReal(data['is_real'])
    }

    function GuessYes() {
        if (isReal == true) {
            setScore(score + 1)
        }
    }

    function GuessNo() {
        if (isReal == false) {
            setScore(score + 1)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getComics()
    },[])

    return(
        <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`}}>
            <Comic caption={caption}/>
            <button onClick={GuessYes}>Yes</button>
            <button onClick={GuessNo}>No</button>
            <button onClick={getComics}>get comics</button>
            <h2>{score}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my code for the Comic component:

```
import React from 'react';
import comic from './Media/comic.png';


export default function Comic (props) {

    return(
        <div>
            <img src={comic}/>
            <h1>{props.caption}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the code that is actually downloading the image:

```
import boto3

def download_comic(num):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
    s3_client.download_file('bucket_name',f'{num}.png', '/path/my-app/src/components/Randomarm/Media/comic.png')
```

Any thoughts on what might remedy this?
Thanks for the help!

## EDIT

Instead of downloading the image to display it, I am just showing the image from my s3 bucket, using `<img src=bucketimage.gif'/>`. This way I avoid the constant rerendering all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because of the state being changed in `useEffect` inside the method `getComics` where you are setting the caption.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Instead of downloading the image, I am just displaying the image from my s3 bucket. That way I avoid downloading the image all together.